# Microsoft Teams : Push Notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-teams

I'm interested in getting push notifications out of Microsoft Teams into my application about changes (sent messages,files) just like in [Outlook push notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations) . I have looked at Office 365 APIs and Graph APIs but, I could not find supporting documentation for Microsoft Teams.

help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment Microsoft Graph does not have any Microsoft Teams APIs in GA, all of them are still on the [/beta endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/teams_api_overview).

In terms of webhooks, it is important to first understand how Microsoft Teams is structured. A sizable number of features surfaced by Teams are actual other services that Teams is utilizing. For example, each "Team" is built on a [Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group) and Files shown in Teams are stored in the Group's [OneDrive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onedrive). So in many cases you can simply use the existing [webhook services](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks) to capture notifications.

Based on your question, there one notable hole however. There currently isn't any webhooks available at the Channel level. So while you can capture a number of messages (changes to membership via Groups, changes to files via OneDrive, etc.), you wouldn't be able to capture conversation events within a Teams Channel.

Comment: highly appreciated your replay. thx.
will i still be able to track sent files in a 1 On 1 conversation when the user is sharing it by uploading it from his computer (not sharing it from oneDrive) if so, how?

Comment: now i see that hooking to user's oneDrive also provide notification when user share a file in a Team's chat when the user upaloding a file **directly from his cumputer** how is that possible?

Comment: You don't listen to the user's OneDrive, you listen to the Group's OneDrive: `groups/{group}/drive`